# Headache - Running a batch file from java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, runtime

So let me start by saying I've gone though every Q&A I can find, both on/off the site, and I'm still hitting a brick wall.

My Program:

All my program does is run a batch file in the same directory as my program.

The code is:

```
try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start startclient.bat");

      } catch (IOException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(MCPFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

      }
    }
```

When I execute the code I get the warning window:

```
Windows cannot find 'startclient.bat'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

If I specify the directory with:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\Folder\\startclient.bat");
```

I get:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Press any key to continue . . . 
C:\Windows\system32>
```

So my uneducated guess is that when I'm calling the batch file through java it's starting in "C:\Windows\system32>" but when I just double click the batch file its starting from the local directory.

How do I fix this?

:(

PS
The kicker is, I actually had this thing working last year but for some reason it won't behave anymore.

PPS
I'm running Win 7 and everything is up to date.

Comment: 11 yrs old and still worth to read: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: *"every Q&A I can find, both on/off the site"*  I cannot understand how you failed to find the document linked by PeterMmm in your  research.  It is mentioned in about every 2nd post related to problems with a `Process`, and your code clearly does not comply with the recommendations contained therein.

Comment: You should first make sure if the "The system cannot find the path specified." is thrown from inside the running "startclient.bat" or from who is trying to run it. Replace it by a trival "test.bat" that does something very simple and non sentive to path/location and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. And Andrew, when I mentioned that I had read them all I was including PeterMmm's.

Comment: I just got it working, and the best/frustrating thing is I didn't have to change any code. All I did was wipe my file associations and boom running code. Damned if I know why it worked, but I'm not complaining :)

Comment: Thanks again for the all the help guys. Nice tip leonbloy, and I'll be checking out that apache link. That link of yours PeterMmm, has saved me more than once in the past. As for Andy's comment... perhaps there's another site better suited to your particular brand of "help" :)

Answer (score 4):

*(I'd simply comment but I don't have enough rep yet to comment hence this "answer")*

I've worked with a lot of batch files called from Java (both on Linux, OS X and Windows) and **the** first thing to know is that you should basically never ever use the constructor taking a string because it is, well, just problematic.

You're better to always create the array of arguments yourself and use this method:

```
public Process exec(String [] cmdArray)
```

You also have to know that correctly consuming the streams can be tricky.  In many cases you're better to simply use libraries that make working with batch files easier.

For example, instead of re-inventing the wheel you may like Apache's commons exec here:

http://commons.apache.org/exec/

Comment: +1 for this answer.  Apache exec allows you to retrieve the script exit code as an integer, which is really important for the Java program executing it.  Also, use "CALL" instead of "START".  If you script needs to spawn a separate window with START inside the .bat script, then it can , but you shouldn't use START from the java execution.  This is because you wont get an exit code when using START.  Also, make sure your batch script exits with "EXIT 1" or "EXIT 0".

Answer (score 2):

When i specify the directory like C:\Folder\startclient.bat I have the back slashes after

```
C:\\ as forward slashes and only one.

C:\\Folder/startclient.bat
```

Below should work for you. Well, i hope so. works for me.

```
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start C:\\Folder/startclient.bat");
    } catch (Exception ex){

    }
```